# OpenCms localization

Tags: localization, locale, opencms

I downloaded OpenCMS 7.5.3
Make setup.
Read doc.

I want to do Hindi locale. Any good detailed tutorial available for multilanguage site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pointers [here](http://www.bng-galiza.org/opencms/opencms/alkacon-documentation/howto_workplace_translation/step1-workplace-translation.html), [here](http://www.opencms.org/en/download/localizations.html) and [here](http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Localization)